# Uninstall & remove emacs (installed via "make")

Tags: emacs, make

I have installed emacs24.4 through instructions on [this site](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-emacs-24-4-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivative-systems/). Now I want to uninstall and remove it completely, but since I haven't installed emacs via `apt-get` I can't seem to remove it either via `apt-get remove` or `apt-get purge` completely. Do you have any idea how to remove it and all files installed with it?

Comment: If you followed these instructions you can 'make uninstall'

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `/opt/emacs` as you have asked `configure` to install everything in `/opt/emacs`

or run `make uninstall` which is safer one.